# Using PHP filter functions like filter_var_array() is there a way to check if length of an input string is less than some value

Tags: php, filter, callback

I have been toying with PHP filter library. I liked it but I am unable to perform a simple filter function. I essentially want to invalidate those values in my input array that are strings and which are longer than certain value. 
Is there a way to do this like,

```
$data = array('input_string_array' => array('aaa', 'abaa', 'abaca'));
$args = array(
    'component'    => array('filter'    => FILTER_DEFAULT,
                            'flags'     => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY, 
                            'options'   => array('min_length' => 1, 'max_length' => 10)
                           )
);

var_dump(filter_var_array($data, $args));
```

I tried this and its giving me error. because presumably there is no min_length/max_length option available. But then how to implement this? Also is there a place where it is mentioned about all such options like max_range, min_range, regexp.

Also I had another doubt, in filters, in FILTER_CALLBACK filter. I wanted to know if there is a way to pass a parameter other than the data to the called function? something like this,

```
echo filter_var($string, FILTER_CALLBACK, array("options"=> array("lengthChecker", "5")));
```

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I can't find any filter to do what you want, but you can of course use a range of 100 to 999 if the variable must have a lenght of 3.

Comment: Well, I tried. Maybe my answer will be helpful, maybe not. But, I give it to you in hopes that it may be useful (if not to you, then to someone else).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless there's a better, more direct filter+option you can use [FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP](http://docs.php.net/filter.filters.validate)

```
$data = array('input_string_array' => array('', 'aaa', 'abaa', 'abaca'));
$args = array(
  'input_string_array' => array(
    'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
    'flags'     => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY|FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE,
    'options'   => array('regexp'=>'/^.{1,3}$/')
  )
);
var_dump(filter_var_array($data, $args));
```

prints

```
array(1) {
  ["input_string_array"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    NULL
    [1]=>
    string(3) "aaa"
    [2]=>
    NULL
    [3]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

To get rid of the NULL elements you can use e.g. [array_filter()](http://php.net/array_filter).

Comment: Better? More direct? Probably not in the context of `filter_var_array()`. But, maybe an anonymous function could work? Maybe not.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the original problem was that the field in the data array was not named the same as the one in the filter array.

Answer (score 1):

### Introduction

You will need at least **PHP 5.4+** for this answer to work (due, at minimum, to the array syntax).

If the goal is to do something like this:

```
$filteredArray = filter_var_array($arrayToFilter, $filterInstuctionsArray);
```

... and use the return results of basic PHP functions (along with decision logic) to check the length (`mb_strlen()`, `strlen()`) of a string, the key is to have an excellent filter instructions Array`. To pass arguments to your callback function (for reuse, encapsulation, and generalization purposes, etc...), I believe there are at least two scenarios.

### Scenarios

**A**) The *class/object* forms.

```
'options' => [$this, 'callbackMethod']

'options' => [$this->object, 'callbackMethod']

'options' => [$object, 'callbackMethod']
```

**B**)The *procedural* form.

```
'options' => 'callbackFunction'
```

### Solutions

**1**) Replace **`$this`** or **`$object`** in scenario **A** with a `new` instance of an object right then and there, passing in any arguments its constructor. This seems unlikely as it smacks of tightly coupled code.

*Alternatively*, one could *inject* a *pre-populated* object into a `Validator` class of some sort and run `filter_input_array()` from within that `Validator` class. Thus, passing arguments to the `callbackMethod` *would not be necessary*.

Or

**2**) Replace **`'callbackFunction'`** in scenario **B** with a [PHP anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and implement the `use` syntax to pass *arguments / constraints* from the `Validator` class to it.

```
function ($value) use ($min, $max) {
    $length = mb_strlen($value, 'UTF-8');
    return ($length >= $min) && ($length <= $max);
}
```

### Attempt #1: Filter Instructions Array with Anonymous Functions

Here is a sequential example for working with scalar values.

```
$filterInstructionsArray[
                            'fName' = ['filter'  => FILTER_CALLBACK,
                                       'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                                       'options' => function ($value) use ($min, $max) {
                                                          $length = mb_strlen($value, 'UTF-8');
                                                          return ($length >= $min) && ($length <= $max);}],
                            'lName' = ['filter'  => FILTER_CALLBACK,
                                       'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                                       'options' => function ($value) use ($min, $max) {
                                                          $length = mb_strlen($value, 'UTF-8');
                                                          return ($length >= $min) && ($length <= $max);}]
                         ];
```

Of course, this violates **DRY** principles. So, you might define the anonymous function as a property of a `Validator` class (or just assign it to a variable), which makes it a named instance of a `Closure` object.

```
private $checkNameLength = function ($value) use ($this->nameMin, $this->nameMax) {
        $length = mb_strlen($value, 'UTF-8');
        return ($length >= $this->nameMin) && ($length <= $this->nameMax);
    };
```

Or

```
$checkNameLength = function ($value) use ($min, $max) {
        $length = mb_strlen($value, 'UTF-8');
        return ($length >= $min) && ($length <= $max);
    };
```

So, my hope is that one of two things will work.

### Attempt #2: Filter Instructions Array with Named Anonymous Functions

```
$filterInstructionsArray[
                            'fName' = ['filter'  => FILTER_CALLBACK,
                                       'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                                       'options' => [$this, 'checkNameLength']]
                         ];
```

Or

```
$filterInstructionsArray[
                            'fName' = ['filter'  => FILTER_CALLBACK,
                                       'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                                       'options' => 'checkNameLength']
                         ];
```

### Potential Complications

The `Closure` instances `$this->checkNameLength` and `$checkNameLength` are objects, not *normal* "methods / functions". But, if PHP does not complain, I will not split hairs. I suppose one could try defining a function inside of an anonymous function.

```
$checkName = function ($value) use ($min, $max) {

        function lengthTest($string, $min, $max){
            $length = mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8');
            return ($length >= $min) && ($length <= $max);
        }
    };
```

Then, your filter instruction array would look like this.

```
$filterInstructionsArray[
                            'fName' = ['filter'  => FILTER_CALLBACK,
                                       'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                                       'options' => [$checkName, 'lengthTest']]
                         ];
```

Or, probably this ...

```
$filterInstructionsArray[
                            'fName' = ['filter'  => FILTER_CALLBACK,
                                       'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                                       'options' => 'lengthTest']
                         ];
```

### Conclusion

There is a better way to create a generic string length checker than using PHP's `filter_var_array()` and anonymous functions. Using `'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP` can make it easy to check the length of a single string, but it is not a substitute for adhering to DRY principles. You will end up having many statements in your filter instructions array like *this*, just to deal with string lengths in an array of input.

```
    //If you just want to test only the lengths first, this is
    //very inefficient. Assume each $regex is only checking string length.

    $filterLengthInstructions = [
                'fName'    => ['filter'  => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
                               'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                               'options' => ['regexp' => $fNameRegex]],
                'lName'    => ['filter'  => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
                               'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                               'options' => ['regexp' => $lNameRegex]],
                'company'  => ['filter'  => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
                               'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                               'options' => ['regexp' => $comanyRegex]],
                'address1' => ['filter'  => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
                               'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                               'options' => ['regexp' => $address1Regex]],
                'address2' => ['filter'  => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
                               'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                               'options' => ['regexp' => $address2Regex]],
                'zip'      => ['filter'  => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
                               'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                               'options' => ['regexp' => $zipRegex]],
                'website'  => ['filter'  => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
                               'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                               'options' => ['regexp' => $urlRegex]],
                'email'  => ['filter'  => FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,
                               'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR,
                               'options' => ['regexp' => $emailRegex]]
     ];
```

You can do this if you are trying to make a *pure* `filter_input_array()` `Validator` class, or routine. But, you will have to make ***multiple*** passes of `filter_var_array()`, with multiple *filter instruction arrays* (because the length of a string is not the only thing that makes it valid, or invalid).

For `website` and `email`, you will want to take advantage of `'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` and `'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL.` At other times, you are going to want to take advantage of `'filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_IP`. Also, especially in the case of `email`, you might want to restrict valid email addresses to a subset of the official RFC with a regular expression. To keep things pure, you would not put that regular expression in the `$filterLengthInstructions`.

The fundamental reasons for wanting to change the `min_length` and `max_length` being able to write the business logic once and use it everywhere.

At minimum, my advice is to create an abstract `Validator` super class and define one (1) method that test string lengths.

[image: Class Validator]

Now, you can divide this method up, or delegate this task to an injected `StringTester` object's method.

[image: Class Validator with StringTester]

Whatever, but by defining concrete child classes of `Validator` all you have to do is define your test parameters in an array, create a loop, and call:

```
$this->testString($string, $min, $max, $pattern, $errorMessage);
```

or

```
$this->stringTester->testString($string, $min, $max, $pattern, $errorMessage);
```

... within the loop. Be sure to account for the $errorMessage.

```
abstract Class Tester
{

}
```

---

```
class StringTester extends Tester
{
    private function testString($string, $min, $max, $pattern, &$errorMessage)
    {
        $length = mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8');

        if ($length < $min) // Test string against minimum length. {
            $errorMessage = 'Too small! ('.$min.' min, ' .$length. ' given.)';
        }
        elseif ($length > $max) // Test string against maximum length. {
            $errorMessage = 'Too large! ('.$max.' max, ' .$length. ' given.)';
        }
        elseif (preg_match($pattern, $string) === 0) // Test string's pattern. {
            $errorMessage = 'Invalid string format!';
        } else {
            $errorMessage = '';  // The error message is the empty string.
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

---

```
abstract Class Validator
{
    // Arrays
    protected $inputArray;
    protected $errorMessagesArray = [];
    protected $stringTestRulesArray;  // I know. I know. :-)

    // Objects
    protected $stringTester;

    // Abstract functions
    abstract public function validate();

    public function __construct(Tester $stringTester, array $inputArray, array $stringTestRutlesArray)
    {
        $this->stringTester = $stringTester;
        $this->inputArray = $inputArray;
        $this->stringTestRulesArray = $stringTestRulesArray
    }

    public function getInput()
    {
        return $this->inputArray;
    }

    public function getErrorMessages()
    {
        return $this->errorMessagesArray();
    }

    protected function validateStrings()
    {
        // Notice how input values correspond to error message elements via $key.
        foreach ($this->stringTestRulesArray as $key = $valuesArr) {           
            $this->stringTester->testString($this->inputArray[$key], $valuesArr['min'], $valuesArr['max'], $valuesArr['pattern'], $this->errorMessagesArray[$key]);
        }

        return;
    }

}
```

---

```
class ContactValidator extends Validator
{
    public function __construct(Tester $stringTester, Sanitizer $sanitizer)
    {
        $stringTestRulesArray = [
                                  'fName' => ['min' => 1, 'max' => 25, 'pattern' => '/[A-Za-z\' -]/'],
                                  'lName' => ['min' => 1, 'max' => 40, 'pattern' => '/[A-Za-z\' -]/']
                                ];

        parent::__construct($stringTester, $sanitizer->getInput(), $stringTestRulesArray);
    }

    public function validate()
    {
        $this->validateStrings();
        //Other, contact form specific validation stuff.
    }
}
```

---

```
class RegisterValidator extends Validator
{
    public function __construct(Tester $stringTester, Sanitizer $sanitizer)
    {
        $stringTestRulesArray = [
                                  'fName' => ['min' => 1, 'max' => 30, 'pattern' => '/[A-Za-z\' -]/'],
                                  'lName' => ['min' => 1, 'max' => 45, 'pattern' => '/[A-Za-z\' -]/']
                                ];

        parent::__construct($stringTester, $sanitizer->getInput(), $stringTestRulesArray);
    }

    public function validate()
    {
        $this->validateStrings();
        //Other, register form specific validation stuff.
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: This is not a complete solution, as forms have *optional fields* that supply and empty string (textboxes, textareas, etc...) and *transient fields* that do not register with the server if they are not checked (checkboxes). Also, recording test results in a `$testResultsArray` allows you to cleverly set CSS values based on a boolean (`true` or `false`). However, I *do* have that complete solution on my computer.

Comment: Also, what about `Tester` objects for integers and floats.

Comment: Lastly, there is the possibility that a string is only valid if it is found to be one within a set of possible values (select lists, etc...). My solution covers this as well.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the second portion of the question related to `FILTER_CALLBACK`.

In PHP 5.4+ you can create a function that returns a static function that will act as a callback.

### Example https://3v4l.org/m3isD

I am including a sample `validate_length` function, feel free to use your own with any desired sanitation or validation. Such as calling `filter_var($value, $options);`

```php
function validate_length($min = 1, $max = null) 
{
    return static function ($value = null) use ($min, $max) {
        $len = strlen($value);
        if (null !== $min && $len < $min) {
           return false;
        }
        if (null !== $max && $len > $max) {
           return false;
        }

        return $value;
    };
}

$_POST = [
   'a' => 'value',
   'b' => '',
   'c' => 'Valid'
];

$result = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, [
    'a' => ['filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK, 'options' => validate_length(null, 4)],
    'b' => ['filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK, 'options' => validate_length(1)],
    'c' => ['filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK, 'options' => validate_length(1, 10)]
]);

var_dump($result);
```

**Result**

```
array(3) {
  ["a"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["b"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["c"]=>
  string(5) "Valid"
}
```

---

As mentioned, you can expand the callback arguments to accept your desired parameters and run additional filters.

### Example https://3v4l.org/83uXu

```php
function validate_length($options = ['min_length' => 1, 'max_length' => null], $filters = null)
{
    return static function ($value = null) use ($options, $filters) {
        $len = strlen($value);
        if (isset($options['min_length']) && $len < $options['min_length']) {
           return false;
        }
        if (isset($options['max_length']) && $len > $options['max_length']) {
           return false;
        }
        if (null !== $filters) {
            return filter_var($value, ...$filters); //php 5.6+ array unpacking operator
        }

        return $value;
    };
}

$a = [
   'a' => 'value',
   'b' => '',
   'c' => 'a@example.com',
   'd' => 'This& is a  Test',
];

$email_filter = [FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL, ['flags' => FILTER_FLAG_EMAIL_UNICODE]];
$string_filter = [FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, ['flags' => FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH]];

$result = filter_var_array($a, [
    'a' => ['filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK, 'options' => validate_length(['max_length' => 4])], 
    'b' => ['filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK, 'options' => validate_length(['min_length' => 1])], 
    'c' => ['filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK, 'options' => validate_length(['min_length' => 1, 'max_length' => 20], $email_filter)],
    'd' => ['filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK, 'options' => validate_length(['min_length' => 1], $string_filter)],
]);

var_dump($result);
```

**Result**

```
array(4) {
  ["a"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["b"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["c"]=>
  string(13) "a@example.com"
  ["d"]=>
  string(20) "This&#38; is a  Test"
}
```