# Validating string length using PHP filter extension

Tags: php, validation, input

How can I validate the length of the input string using PHP filter extension?

There are min_range and max_range options for validating integer, but what should I do in case of a string?

Comment: Better way is to use a regular expression please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489260/using-php-filter-functions-like-filter-var-array-is-there-a-way-to-check-if-le

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using PHP filter functions like filter\_var\_array() is there a way to check if length of an input string is less than some value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489260/using-php-filter-functions-like-filter-var-array-is-there-a-way-to-check-if-le)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php
  foreach (filter_list() as $id =>$filter) {
      echo '<tr><td>' . $filter . '</td><td>' . filter_id($filter) . '</td></tr>';
  }
  ?>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
// $_POST['name'] = "Robert <b>hello</b>";
var_dump(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
// Output: string(12) "Robert hello"

// $_POST['email'] = "mail@example.com";
var_dump(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
// Output: string(16) "mail@example.com"

// $_POST['age'] = "22";
var_dump(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'age', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                        array('options' => array('min_range' => 18,
                                                'max_range' => 28)
                        )));
// Output: int(22)
```

Comment: Like this: I can validate the range of an integer using $var = filter_var('0755', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('min_range'=>5)); but in case of a string no options available for checking the length

Comment: I think no options to find the string length using php filter extension.

Comment: Because, in php filter functions does not have to find string length particularly. http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php

Comment: true only three keys available in the options array default, min_range, max_range

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25976468/how-to-use-the-options-array-in-filter-input-filter-var) this questine answers the available options

Comment: there is no option for validating string length.., only possible solution is to define a callback

Answer (score -1):

strlen is used to get the string length then you can add validation according to you.

```
 $strlth =  strlen("Hello");

    if($strlth < 6){
      echo "invalid string"
    }else{
      your stuff
    }
```

Comment: Its OK. but I want do it with filter_input_array function, so that I can filter all the input variables at once.

Comment: ^ You need to loop the super global and check in your iteration that way. $_GET, $_POST etc all arrays if initialized and populated. Just throw a foreach.